# How to map a location to a path in NGINX

Tags: nginx

I have an nginx setup where I need to map specific url paths to server paths. For example I need `example.test/myapp/` to go to the following directory in the server: `/apps/myapp/web`

I tried adding the following location block:

```
location /myapp/
{
    root /apps/myapp/web;
}
```

but if I go to `example.test/myapp/` or `example.test/myapp` I get a 404.

As far as I can tell according to the [docs](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/) this location should capture anything with a path that starts with `/myapp/` and it's the only location block in the server so there's no chance of conflict. Also I've tried changing the location to point to the root (i.e. `location /`) and it works fine so it's not a problem of the wrong server path or missing files. What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

nginx resolves file paths by using following strategy:

1. Use path from `root` directive
2. Add URI from request after the directive.

Now, in your case:

1. `root` is `/apps/myapp/web`.
2. URI from `example.test/myapp/` is `/myapp/`.

Therefore nginx looks up files in `/apps/myapp/web/myapp/` directory for that request.

If you want that `/myapp/` URI will get files from `/apps/myapp/web/` directory, you need to use the `alias` directive:

```
location /myapp/ {
    alias /apps/myapp/web/;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Where I got turned around is with the example in the docs where they say: `location ~ \.(mp3|mp4) { root /www/media; }` will return all video files at `www/media`. So prefix locations append the URI but regular expression locations don't?

Comment: Yes, regular expressions don't append the URI, because it is difficult to determine which part of the regular expression match should be appended.

Comment: @Mattia No, regex locations follow the same rule as normal location blocks, URL `/myapp/test.mp4`, root `/www/media` becomes `/www/media/myapp/test.mp4`

Comment: using the alias results in returning 403s for everything. (I know it's not actually a permissions issue since I was able to server the files with other location blocks). It was fixed by adding a trailing slash to the alias: `alias /apps/myapp/web/`. Not sure why that is...

Comment: Interesting. I don't use `alias` myself, so I didn't know it required slash at the end. Good that you figured it out, I updated my answer.